# Custom Table View Cell Not Swiping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableViewController that has one custom prototype cell with the identifier "regularCell" set in Storyboard. The TableViewController is of the class TimelineTableViewController.swift and the cell is of the class TimelineTableViewCell.swift.swift both set in Storyboard.

In TimelineTableViewController.swift:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.events.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("regularCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .None
        let event = events[indexPath.row]
        cell.content.text = event.content
        cell.name.text = event.name
        cell.metadata.text = event.metadata
        return cell
    }

}
```

And in TimelineTableViewCell.swift I try to make the cell swipe-able but nothing happens and the pan gesture recognizer isn't being called.

```
import UIKit

class TimelineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var originalCenter = CGPoint()
var deleteOnDragRelease = false

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var content: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var metadata: UILabel!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    var recognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
    recognizer.delegate = self
    addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    // 1
    if recognizer.state == .Began {
        // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
        originalCenter = center
    }
    // 2
    if recognizer.state == .Changed {
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
        center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
        // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
        deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
    }
    // 3
    if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
        let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
            width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
        if !deleteOnDragRelease {
            // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
        }
    }
}
override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(superview!)
        if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}

}
```

Would anyone happen to know what I am doing wrong? The cells in the table load perfectly but they just aren't swipeable as if I never added anything. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated

Comment: Try setting userInteractionEnabled = true in init method of cell

Comment: Didn't work :( And the cells are already interactable since I can click on them and they get highlighted @zellb

Comment: You have to set the tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath method to enable swipe to delete: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Don't think that's it since the docs say: "If this method is not implemented, all rows are assumed to be editable." @DejanSkledar

Comment: Can you check if gestureRecognizerShouldBegin its called ?

Comment: @zellb neither gestureRecognizerShouldBegin nor handlePlan are being called. My guess is my cells are not of the custom cells? This doesn't make sense though since in tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath: the following is declared let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("regularCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell

Comment: override gesture recognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer method to return true and check the results please

Comment: @zellb no effect at all. Thanks for the help though, this has stumped me for over an hour now

Comment: It looks very strange let me further investigate this

Comment: Why not just use the default methods to recognize a swipe?

Comment: @zellb see the solution below 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out! When adding the gesture recognizer do so in awakeFromNib. 
Here's the working code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        var panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePan:")
        panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    }
    func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // 1
        if recognizer.state == .Began {
            // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
            originalCenter = center
        }
        // 2
        if recognizer.state == .Changed {
            let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self)
            center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
            // has the user dragged the item far enough to initiate a delete/complete?
            deleteOnDragRelease = frame.origin.x < -frame.size.width / 2.0
        }
        // 3
        if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            if !deleteOnDragRelease {
                // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
            }
        }
    }
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(superview!)
            if fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return false
    }
```

Do not bother with overriding init. Another alternative solution as suggested by a friend, would be to add a scrollview to the cell content view and work from there. Hope this helps!
And thanks to all who helped!