# Is there a way to navigate from a tableViewCell to another view controller when a cell is swiped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So here's how I made my swiping cells: [Custom Table View Cell Not Swiping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358071/custom-table-view-cell-not-swiping). Anyway I was wondering if there was a way of transitioning from a table view to another view controller when a cell is swiped leftwards. I know it can be done when a cell is tapped and calling performSegueWithIdentifier in didSelectRowAtIndexPath but have never seen an example of when a cell is swiped. I tried adding `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("detail", sender: self)` to the logic of the swipe

```
if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            // the frame this cell had before user dragged it
            let originalFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: frame.origin.y,
                width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
            if !reserveOnDragRelease {
                // if the item is not being deleted, snap back to the original location
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = originalFrame})
            } else {
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.frame = CGRectMake(-self.bounds.size.width, originalFrame.origin.y, originalFrame.width, originalFrame.height)})
            // Added it here 

            }
        }
```

but got the error that the CustomTableViewCell  does not have a member named performSegueWithIdentifier. Anyone have any insight?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, `performSegueWithIdentifier` is a `UIViewController` method, so a `UIView` object will never be able to receive it.

Second, I don't recommend you to do switch View Controller while swipping, because it is kind of violation to iOS human-machine interface principles. People get used to swipe to delete or edit it, not navigating to next view controller.

But If you are really sure you want to do this, simply get your current UIViewController object and you are good to go. But getting view controller object inside a view is not a good design I think. You probably want to take a look at the UITableViewDelegate protocol to find a better place. Also, you could leverage your swipe gesture's delegate to do your actions.

You don't necesarrily to insist using `performSegueWithIdentifier`, there are lots of ways to switch view controllers.

Comment: I'm kind of making the cells a la Tweetbot where swiping the cell opens it in detail and tapping on it expands. Why would getting the view controller object inside the view not be a good idea? What happens exactly?

Comment: Usually a view controller holds a UIView object, and you are adding your subviews in this UIView object. So one thing is if your custom views holds a reference to view controller, you might be careful not introducing `retain cycles`. And usually View talks to ViewController via notification or delegate, not directly calling view controller methods. You are not forbidden to do so, but it is a good pattern to follow, since many experienced people think this is the best way. More flexible, and less bugs

Comment: besides, I think you should think about people's habbits - make less chances to let people make mistakes. That's important for a good app to always think about how people feels while using apps. You think your design is creative, but people may think it violates what they are used to do without thinking.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `theCustomTableViewCell` doesn't have a method called `performSegueWithIdentifier` but UIViewController has that method

Try to delegate `UITableViewDelegate` and use this method to get item individually:

```
    myTableView.delegate = self

    ////////////////////////////

    var myItems: [String: Bool] = [:]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
        let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
        // add to self.selectedItems
        myItems[itemId[1]] = true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
        let itemId = selectedItem.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
        // remove from self.selectedItems
        myItems[itemId[1]] = nil
    }
```